# No API definition provided Swagger after deploy

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm use springdoc-openapp in spring-boot app. When I run it on localhost - it's work.

When I deploy it on server - it's not work.

First it show me default swagger url.

I use

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```

And now it shows - No API definition provided. Help, please.